# passing a list of varchars into plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to prepare a function which would be called

```
select gettvmlistic3('IC','AUTABB',array['565,568,569,570,572,573,574,575,576,577,578'])
```

the declaratin of my function is

```
create or replace function getTVMListIC3(operatorName varchar,groupid varchar, ids varchar[])
returns varchar as $$
declare
tvms varchar[];
res varchar;
begin
EXECUTE format('SELECT ARRAY (SELECT id from "%s".dictionary where groupid = ''%s'' and id = ANY(''%s'') order by id)', operatorName, groupid, ids) INTO tvms;
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(tvms, ',') INTO res;
return res;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

but the result I get is empty. In fact I should receive the same number of elements as in the array provided. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an array with a single element.

If you want to pass multiple elements you need to use:

```
array['565','568','569','570','572','573','574','575','576','577','578']
```

---

But you shouldn't concatenate the parameter values like that.

Use placeholders (`$1`) in the dynamic SQL and pass the values with the `USING` clause. Identifiers should be injected with the `%I` in the format() function:

You also don't need to first select into an array and then convert that to a string again. You can aggregate everything into a single string right away.

```
create or replace function getTVMListIC3(operatorName varchar, groupid varchar, ids varchar[])
  returns varchar 
as $$
declare
  res varchar;
begin
  EXECUTE format($sql$ 
                 SELECT string_agg(id::text, ',' order by id) 
                 from %I.dictionary 
                 where groupid = $1 
                   and id = ANY($2)
                 $sql$, operatorName) 
    INTO res
    using groupid, ids;

  return res;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

Those strings look like numbers. If that is the case it's better to define the parameter as `int[]` and then pass the list of number as:

```
array[565,568,569,570,572,573,574,575,576,577,578]
```

Comment: hmm thanks, but now when I'm calling the function like select getTVMListIC3('IC', 'AUTABB', array['565','568','569','570','572','573','574','575','576','577','578']) I got following error : 
LINE 1: SELECT string_agg(id::text, 
                                    ^
QUERY:  SELECT string_agg(id::text, 
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "gettvmlistic3" line 5 at instrukcja EXECUTE

Comment: @mario: ah, sorry. Got the quoting in the function wrong